# Assigning to struct member using structType*&

Tags: c++, pointers

I am ok with pointers, but am confused when dealing with ***test*& t*** in this program. My understanding, which may be incorrect, is that t contains the address of root and root itself is a pointer to an undeclared(?) struct of type test. I understand what the error means. I am essentially saying 0="abc", but I am unsure of the proper way to assign a new value to root.detailText through t by using the read function. I cant change anything outside the body of the read function.

test.cpp The file where I get the error.

```
void test::read (istream& in, test*& t)
{
    cout<<"test "<<&t->detailText<<" test";
    if (&t->detailText == 0){ // Works fine.
        &t->detailText = "abc"; //error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
     }
}
```

test.h

```
struct test {
  std::string detailText;
  test* ifYes;
  test* ifNo;

  test (std::string q, test* yes = NULL, test* no = NULL)
    : detailText(q), ifYes(yes), ifNo(no)
    {}

  static void read (std::istream& in, test*& t);
  static void write (std::ostream& out, const test* root);
    
private:
  friend std::istream& operator>> (std::istream&, test*&);
  friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream&, const test*);

};
inline
std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& in, test*& n)
{
  test::read (in, n);
  return in;
}
```

Other file that begins the read process

```
  test* root = 0;
  {
    ifstream in (fileName);
    if (in.good())
      in >> root;
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... when dealing with test*& t in this program. My understanding, which may be incorrect, is that t contains the address of root and root itself is a pointer to an undeclared(?) struct of type test ...

`root` itself is a `test*`, that's correct. But `t` is a *reference* to `root`, not the address of `root`. So you should use `t` just as you would use `root`, and be aware that modifying `t` will modify `root`.

So in your function you shouldn't be using `&` at all. You just need:

```
void test::read (istream& in, test*& t)
{
    if (t != nullptr) { 
        cout<<"test "<< t->detailText << " test";
        t->detailText = "abc"; 
    }
}
```

Note that you should be checking if `t` is a valid pointer, before dereferencing it to look at `detailText`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I haven't seen *& before and it threw me off and I just assumed it was more complicated than it was.

Comment: Read up on how references work, *separately* from pointers, and then come back to this example, it'll make much more sense :)

Answer (score 0):

Confusion regarding types is a common problem when learning C++. I find it easier to read from right to left.

Given

```
 test*& t
```

if you read from right to left, it would read as

`t` is a reference to a pointer to a `test` object.